# Using indexRedirect in a route configuration object

Tags: react-router

I was wondering if it's possible to use "indexRedirect" in a route configuration object (so without using JSX).

I tried without success, so I assumed that this isn't supported at the moment, but then my issue (https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/issues/3150) was closed without comment, so I still don't know if it's because the feature is already there but I misuse it, or because this is a unwanted feature.

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 2):

As described [in the docs](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/IndexRoutes.md), the equivalent to indexRedirect using a plain configuration object looks like this

```
const routes = [{
  path: '/',
  component: App,
  indexRoute: { onEnter: (nextState, replace) => replace('/welcome') },
  childRoutes: [
    { path: 'welcome', component: Welcome },
    { path: 'about', component: About }
  ]
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using plain routes config it's a bit more low level API, and there is no point of having special `redirect` or `indexRedirect` keys in the routes object. Instead you could use `onEnter` to accomplish a redirect. Here is how:

```jsx
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { Router, browserHistory } from 'react-router'

const Home = () => <h3>Home</h3>

const About = () => <h3>About</h3>

const routes = [{
  path: '/',
  component: Home,
  onEnter: (nextState, replace) => replace('/about')
}, {
  path: '/about',
  component: About
}]

render(
  <Router history={browserHistory} routes={routes} />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Edit: added this into [docs](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/0768baac21dd71583310b0b4b00db4db0c124ecf/docs/guides/RouteConfiguration.md#redirect-using-plain-routes-configuration) as well.

Comment: I followed the issue template :


"Have a feature request?
Remove the template from below and provide thoughtful commentary *and code samples* on what this feature means for your product. What will it allow you to do that you can't do today? How will it make current work-arounds straightforward? What potential bugs and edge cases does it help to avoid? etc. Please keep it product-centric."


I asked for a feature request, I specified it in my issue title.


Your answer works for full path, but I wanted to have the IndexRedirect behaviour with relative path.


Thank you anyway

Answer (score 0):

I would appreciate the same thing as JGX: working relative paths for this kind of redirecting

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you [earn](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/146472/169503) sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) on any post. If you have a related but different question, [ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) referencing this one if it will help provide context.